# Accessing WooCommerce subscription data using a comma delimited string of order id's

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to use the `wcs_get_subscriptions` function to retrieve subscription information to create printable labels.

I have the plugin passing a comma delimited list of order id's within the querystring into the script, but I'm not sure how to pass the id string into the function.

```
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions(array( 'subscriptions_per_page' => -1,
                'subscription_status' => array('active'), 
                'post_id' => array(123,456,789) ));
foreach($subscriptions as $sub){ 
     echo $sub->get_shipping_city(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**In short, you can't with the `wcs_get_subscriptions` function:**

The `wcs_get_subscriptions` function unfortunately does not currently allow an array for the `order_id` parameter. Looking at the source for the function, it only takes a single numeric value ("*The post ID of a shop_order post/WC_Order object which was used to create the subscription*"), then uses that as the `post_parent` in a `get_posts` call that returns a list of IDs; it then runs wcs_get_subscription on each one to create the final array that's returned. It's somewhat limited in not allowing all of the arguments that get_posts does.

Source for the `wcs_get_subscriptions` function is available here:
https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/wcs-functions.php

**Alternative solution to do what you need:**

You can use [get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#parameters), matching other similar arguments that `wcs_get_subscriptions` uses, with the `post_parent__in` parameter:

> 'post_parent__in' (array) An array containing parent page IDs to query
>   child pages from.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Get an array of WooCommerce subscriptions in form of post_id => WC_Subscription.
 * Basically returns what wcs_get_subcriptions does, but allows supplying
 * additional arguments to get_posts.
 * @param array $get_post_args Additional arguments for get_posts function in WordPress
 * @return array Subscription details in post_id => WC_Subscription form.
 */
function get_wcs_subscription_posts($get_post_args){
  // Find array of post IDs for WooCommerce Subscriptions.
  $get_post_args = wp_parse_args( $get_post_args, array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_subscription',
    'post_status' => array('active'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'orderby' => 'date'
  ));
  $subscription_post_ids = get_posts( $get_post_args );

  // Create array of subscriptions in form of post_id => WC_Subscription
  $subscriptions = array();
  foreach ( $subscription_post_ids as $post_id ) {
    $subscriptions[ $post_id ] = wcs_get_subscription( $post_id );
  }
  return $subscriptions;
}

get_wcs_subscription_posts(array(
    'post_parent__in' => array(123, 456, 789)
));
```

If you had the Subscription IDs rather than the Order IDs, you could also use `post__in`. Hope that helps.